# can i add FLVplayback to .fla file -- in adobe flash

Tags: flash, adobe

so the question is can i add the FLV playback to my .fla file and how? i am not able to add .fla as a source to the FLVPlayback once dragging it into my timeline.

how can i add the ability to stop pause and play my animation? (its .fla file and i opened actionsctipt3).

i would super appreciate any answers.

Answer (score 1):

The flvplayback is only for video. To pause and play your timeline animation you must add buttons to the stage and add `stop()` and `play()` actionscript commands to the onrelease events of the buttons. You could also add a button with a `gotoAndStop(1)` command to act as a stop button, since the command makes the play head go to the first frame and stop there.

Hope I could help.